# How to use user input in Eclipse RCP application?

Tags: java, eclipse-plugin, swt, eclipse-rcp, jface

Here is an extract of my Eclipse RCP application I am working on:

[image: UML diagram]

**Description:** In the method `createContents(Composite)` inside the class `ContainerSelectionDialog` I am calling `createComposite(Composite)` in `MyComposite`, which inherits from the abstract class `AbstractCompositeProxy`:

```
TabFolder folder = new TabFolder((Composite) dialogArea, SWT.TOP);
Composite comp = (Composite) super.createDialogArea(folder);
TabItem tab = new TabItem(folder, SWT.NONE);
tab.setText("Header");
tab.setControl(compositeProxy
        .createComposite(comp));
```

Inside `createComposite(Composite)` I am creating SWT widgets like `org.eclipse.swt.widgets.Text`, `org.eclipse.swt.widgets.Combo` and so on. Example:

```
Label label = new Label(parentComposite, SWT.NONE);
label.setText("Something");

Text text = new Text(parentComposite, SWT.BORDER);
GridData gridData = new GridData();
gridData.horizontalAlignment = SWT.FILL;
gridData.grabExcessHorizontalSpace = true;
text.setLayoutData(gridData);
```

So inside my Eclipse RCP application, the user can open a dialog with the defined widget elements, where he can input data. In `okPressed()`, in the class `ContainerSelectionDialog` I want to read the values, the user put in, by using `getSettings()` from `MyComposite`:

```
@Override
protected void okPressed() {
    List<Object> results = new ArrayList<>();
    results.add(abstractCompositeProxy.getSimulationSettings());
    setResult(results);
    super.okPressed();
}
```

This is not my design decision. I am just trying to understand the following: How to use the `getSettings()` method inside `okPressed()`, to get the values?

Hope this is enough information, otherwise I will give additional info in the comments. I would appriciate any help!

Comment: What exactly is the problem with invoking a method (getSimulationSettings) on an object (abstractCompositeProxy)? The method signature appears weird, but might be okay for you. I would expect getSimulationSettings returning a List of Setting-instances, which might lead to invoke "addAll" on results, instead of add.

Answer (score 0):

Access `compositeProxy` from `okPressed()` in the same way you do in `createContents()`.